# How can I flip the signs of this denominator without affecting the rest of the equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve an equation for x and I seem to be making a mistake in how I multiply by -1. First I simplified the equation to:

$$\frac{(x-1)(x-1)}{2(1-x)} = -3$$

I changed the order of the denominator to $2(-x+1)$. I then multiplied both sides of the equation by -1, or $\frac{-1}{1}$, to get:

$$\frac{(-x+1)(-x+1)}{2(-x+1)} = 3$$

This then simplifies to $-5$, but the correct answer is $7$.

The book appears to arrive at the same simplification at the top of the post, but then takes a different route to solving that I can't wrap my head around.

The book goes from:

$$\frac{(x-1)(x-1)}{2(1-x)} = -3$$

To:

$$\frac{(x-1)(x-1)}{2(x-1)} = -3$$

How were they able to simply flip the signs in the $(1-x)$ of the denominator seemingly without affecting any other part of the equation? If you multiply by $-1$ wouldn't that mean $-3$ would become $+3$? I used to do equations like this automatically when I was in school, now I feel lost!

Edit: Here is an actual image of the textbook's problem & steps:

[image: textbook problem]

Comment: Are you sure it's still $-3$?

Comment: $\frac{(x-1)(x-1)}{2(1-x)}\neq \frac{(x-1)(x-1)}{2(x-1)}$

Comment: You multiplied the top *and* bottom by $-1$ and said it was equal to $3$, which is false

Comment: Okay, so I am not crazy. It looks like the book made a mistake and left the equation equal to -3 after multiplying by -1. But then, if they are multiplying by $\frac{1}{-1}$ then why doesn't the denominator become $-2(x-1)$? And what have I done wrong in my steps that seems to result in a different answer?

Comment: @AndresMejia When I multiplied by -1 all I changed was the top, from $(x-1)(x-1)$ to $(-x+1)(-x+1)$. I did not alter the bottom in any way except rearranging the terms.

Comment: good point. I'm sorry. However, you did multiply both factors in the numerator, which is incorrect. Sorry, I just knew it was being doubled somewhere

Comment: It is a typo...it is clear from the next step that it should have been equal to 3, not -3

Answer (score 4):

When you multiply a product by $\;-1\;$ you must only multiply one factor, not both. In your case it is simpler: just "take out" the minus sign from the denominator: $\;2(1-x)=-2(x-1)\;$:

$$\frac{(x-1)(x-1)}{2(1-x)}=-3\implies -\frac{(x-1)(x-1)}{2(x-1)}=-3\implies$$

$$\implies\frac{x-1}2=3\implies \color{red}{x=7}$$

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. So would you say that my mistake was distributing -1 in the numerator rather than multiplying by -1? In other words, I should have done $(-1)(x-1)(x-1)$ and not $(-1)(x-1)(-1)(x-1)$?

Comment: It is much easier to simply manipulate the denominator and cancel the common factors.  @Joanpemo's method (and the textbook...) makes this obvious...

Comment: Yes...but observe that what you did is ALMOST! You simply shouldn't have changed the minus in fron of $\;3\;$, that's all.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven I understand what you mean, I'm just curios about the fundamentals of manipulating the equation. I'm not being tested on this material or anything, just trying to genuinely understand it. I just ran through the problem again and really it seems just as easy to manipulate the numerator as denominator. The numerator simply becomes $(1-x)(x-1)$ which cancels with the $(1-x)$ in the denominator and -3 becomes 3. Looks like I'm arriving at the right answer now.

Answer (score 2):

In your problem you start with 
$$\frac{(x-1)(x-1)}{2(1-x)}=-3$$

Note that $(x-1)(x-1)=(-x+1)(-x+1)$, since

$$(x-1)(x-1)=(-1)(-x+1)(-1)(-x+1)$$

so you never multiplied your left hand side by $-1$...

Comment: no you didn't...$(1-x)=(-x+1)$ by the commutative property...

Comment: no problem!  I'm still concerned that your textbook is wrong because that is also wrong...

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but  I cannot wrap my head around how (x-1)(x-1) = (-x+1)(-x+1). That is not the commutative property, right? Let me get a screenshot from my textbook.

Comment: Note what i said above...factor out a -1 from each linear factor.  $$(x-1)=(-1)(-x+1)$$  but you have two of these $(-1)$ factors, so $(-1)(-1)=1$

Comment: @Tyler, this is the commutative property: $\;a+b=b+a\;$ , and then $\;x-1=-1+x\;$, and this is true for each and all factors. But then remember that $\;(-1)(-1)=1\;$ , so: $\;x-1=-(-x+1)\implies (x-1)(x-1)=(-1)(-1)(-x+1)(-x+1)=(-x+1)(-x+1)\;$